# Correct algorithm for a bouncing ball

Tags: c++, matrix, arduino, pixel, esp32

I'm trying to bounce a ball on a matrix. I have tried implementing two algorithms but both seem to have pros and cons. And with a bit of searching, I have been unable to find further reading material for a better algorithm.

Could anyone identify what I'm even trying to do or search! Thank you.

(I have only implemented this in 1 dimension for ease currently)

The first method has a velocity and we add it to the y, this produces a good result, but we are skipping pixels making it look jumpy.

```
while(true){
  effects.leds[XY(x,y)] = CRGB(0,0,0);//remove old ball
  y = y + (int)round(yd);//move ball
  yd = yd - gravity;//apply some gravity
  if(y<1)//check ball hitting the ground
    yd = 0.8 * -yd;//make xd a positive number and take some energy off it.
  if(y< 3 &&  fabs(yd)<1)//give the ball some momentum (its now resting on the floor).
    yd =  random(0,5);
  if(y < 0)//if the ball went too low
    y = 0;
  if(x>-1 && x<64 && y>-1 && y<64)//check ball is within our matrix and then draw
    effects.leds[XY(x,y)] = CRGB(255,255,255);
  delay(10);
}
```

The second algorithm in hopes to improve on the first, is less jumpy, but very unnatural looking!

```
while(true)
    {
      effects.leds[XY(x,y)] = CRGB(0,0,0); //remove oldball.
    if(yd > 1)//move the ball higher or lower
      y = y + 1;
    else
      y = y - 1;  
      yd = yd - gravity; //apply some gravity
      
      if(y<1)//check ball hitting the ground
        yd = 0.8 * -yd;//make xd a positive number and take some energy off it.
      if(y< 3 &&  fabs(yd)<1)//give the ball some momentum (its now resting on the floor).
        yd = random(0,5);
      if(y < 0)
        y = 0;
      //check ball is within our matrix and then draw
      if(x>-1 && x<64 && y>-1 && y<64)
        effects.leds[XY(x,y)] = CRGB(255,255,255);
    if(yd*yd < 40)
      delay(40 - yd*yd);
    }
```

P.S You can assume drawing happens instantly and I'm using `pxmatrix` with an ESP32 if you are interested.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like (just idea - not the actual c++ code)

```
y = START_HEIGHT
v = START_VELOCITY
a = G(-9.1) // const
loop:
  v += G * dt
  dy = v * dt - v * AIR_RESISTENCE
  y += dy
  if (y < 0) {
    v = -v * ENGERGY_LOST_ON_ELASTIC_JUMP(0.94)
    y += abs(dy) - y
  }
  go to loop
```

Comment: Thank you, I’m sure this would look even more realistic, but sadly this would surely have a similar ‘jumpy’ look to it like in my algorithm 1? Where by, I’m changing my velocity but skipping several pixels out causing that jumpy look? Thank you however.